# Captar Strings Iniciadas com %t e %u

Tags: c, arduino

Qual modificação  posso fazer para captar umidade e temperatura da minha porta serial para inserir dentro de uma variável a umidade que é imprimida na porta serial como %u00.00 e a temperatura %t00.00.

Geralmente com caracteres unicos, exemplo 'O',eu uso parte da função abaixo, agora o que não estou conseguindo é que este buffer filtre apenas os valores que começem em %t ou %u para que eu guarde em uma variável e imprima no meu LCD.

```
void recebeir(){
char valorlido = Serial.read();
if (valorlido == 'O'){ //liga ou desliga a tv
{ 
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) //Envia um flash de led com 3 comandos
irsend.sendRaw(S_pwr,68,38); //código clonado
delay(52);
 }
 Serial.println("Liguei ou Desliguei a TV");
 }
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não coneço Arduino, mas pela sua explicação e pelo código que você mostrou a lógica poderia ser mais ou menos assim:

```
void recebeir()
{
   char temp[5], umid[5];

   char valorlido = Serial.read();

   if (valorlido == 'O')
   { //liga ou desliga a tv
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) //Envia um flash de led com 3 comandos
          irsend.sendRaw(S_pwr,68,38); //código clonado
      delay(52);
      Serial.println("Liguei ou Desliguei a TV");
   }

   else if (valorlido == '%')
   {
      // leitura de 't' ou 'u'
      valorlido = Serial.read();
      if (valorlido == 't')
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              temp[i] = Serial.read();
          // temp agora tem a temperatura: nn.nn
      }
      else if (valorlido == 'u')
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              umid[i] = Serial.read();
          // umid agora tem a umidade: nn.nn
      }
      else
      {
         // nao e' 't' nem 'u'
         // ...
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // nao e' 'O' nem '%'
      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Boa, não tinha pensado desta forma. Hoje não consigo mais testar porque guardei minhas placas, mas vou tentar essa logica e posto aqui se funcionou.
Obrigado até o momento.